# Rxjs Countdown Timer using SwitchMap

Tags: javascript, timer, rxjs

RXJS countdown timer stops suddenly and i am able find out it is canceled by switchMap when trustworthy data is not emitted.

How to fix it? I need to start the timer by clicking the button. 
Please find the jsbin of my example

```js
   

 const start = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.querySelector('#btn'), 'click');
    
    start
      .switchMap(() => {
        return Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000)
          .takeUntil(Rx.Observable.timer(60000 + 1000))
      })
      .map((value) => 60000 - value * 1000)
      .map(function(i) {
        return 'Timer (second): ' + i / 1000;
      }).subscribe(function(text) {
        var container = document.querySelector('#app');
        container.textContent = text;
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>RxJS 5 Operators</title>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.3/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id='btn'> start </button>
    <p id='app'></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would start fixing it by formatting the code properly.

Comment: I've implemented a countdown in a small app to showcase ngrx, called [pizza-sync](https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync/blob/3fd0490c6297f12a3026ff7863c87ec67ed98233/frontend/src/app/shared/services/countdown.service.ts). It might help you :)

Comment: @artur grzesiak Done :) code formatted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `takeUntil(...)` to `take(...)`

**from:**

```
.takeUntil(Rx.Observable.timer(60000 + 1000))
```

**to:**

```
.take(60000 / 1000 + 1)
```

**Guessing reason:**

If timer has accumulated temporal error, `takeUntil` could be fired before expected timer event occured.

```
      time
[0]   0.000
[1]   1.103
...
[59] 60.234
     61.003 <- takeUntil fired
[60] 61.123 <- expected last event lost
```

Comment: Thanks to  @thatsseeyou. This seems to be working. Could you please explain the reason? I am accepting your answer

Comment: @satz I added reason to the post.

Comment: it could be a valid one, switchmap will do rest ,when the data is not trsutworthy. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const start$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.querySelector('#btn'), 'click');

start$
  .switchMap(()=> {
    return Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000)
      .takeUntil(Rx.Observable.timer(3000 + 1000))
      .map(value => 3000 - value * 1000)
      .map(function (i) {
        return 'Timer (second): ' + i/1000;
      });
  })
  .subscribe(function (text) {
    var container = document.querySelector('#app');
    container.textContent = text;
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>RxJS 5 Operators</title>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.3/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id='btn'> start </button>
    <p id='app'></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any difference in your code except the duration time.